# To what extent can I trust natural recursion

Tags: recursion, programming-languages

Lets say I want to code fibonatchi numbers. Beside the fact I will need two base cases. Can I trust that fibonatch(n-2) works like fibonatchi(n-1). My question does trust natural recursion works on next level only or can it be multiple levels

Comment: What do you mean by "trust", and what do you mean by "natural recursion"?

Comment: Trust means trusting tha value of the function is correct and natural recursion is term used in course i am taking and is repeated in how to design programs book

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.